# Localhost run Node.js app can't connect to mongolabs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mlab

I'm pretty new to Mongo and Node.  I set up a test account on mongolabs and created a new admin user.  Then in my localhost I required mongoose and used.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:password@ds045475.mongolab.com:45475/nodelearn', function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err); 
});
```

however, it keeps throwing the error: [MongoError, connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONN REFUSED'.  I have the mongolab address right, and I have mongoose imported.  I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: In mongolabs, did you create a user named `admin`?

Comment: Traffic from your network to MongoLab Sandbox server might be blocked. Try the troubleshooting guide to determine where the disconnect might be: http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#help